# Postponing the release of an element from resource when the next queue is full

Tags: python, while-loop, simpy

I used some inputs that I got from this forum and got quite far while using simpy for the first time in my life for university. Now my question remains:

- I can see that the customer/entity goes through process0 and the process1_broker but gets stuck right after entering process1. It never comes out. What am I doing wrong? I followed the code from an earlier answer directly, where only 1 queue is in place (see the comment section for this).

```
class Entity(object):
    pass

def process0(env, entity, process_0_res, process_1_q):
    print(f' {env.now} customer {entity.id} is in system')
    with process_0_res.request() as res_req:
        yield res_req
        yield env.timeout(0.5)
        print(f'{env.now} customer {entity.id} is in queue 1')
        yield process_1_q.put(entity)

def process1_broker(env, process_1_q, process_1_res):
    while True:
        # is resource available?
        res_req = process_1_res.request()
        yield res_req
        # is customer available?
        entity = yield process_1_q.get()
        # save resource request to release later
        entity.res_req = res_req
        # start process
        env.process(process1(env,entity,process_1_res, process_2_q))

def process1(env, entity, process_1_res, process_2_q):
    print(f' {env.now} customer {entity.id} in process 1')
    with process_1_res.request() as res_req:
        yield res_req
        yield env.timeout(2)
        print(f' {env.now} customer {entity.id} done with process 1')
        yield process_2_q.put(entity)


def process2_broker(env, process_2_q, process_2_res):
    while True:
        res_req = process_2_res.request()
        yield res_req
        entity = yield process_2_q.get()
        entity.res_req = res_req
        env.process(process2(env,entity,process_2_res, process_3_q))

def process2(env, entity, process_2_res, process_3_q):
    print(f' {env.now} customer {entity.id} in process 2')
    with process_2_res.request() as res_req:
        yield res_req
        yield env.timeout(np.random.exponential(mu[1]))
        yield process_3_q.put(entity)
        
def process3_broker(env, process_3_q, process_3_res):
    while True:
        res_req = process_3_res.request()
        yield res_req
        entity = yield process_3_q.get()
        entity.res_req = res_req
        env.process(process3(env,entity,process_3_res, process_4_q))

def process3(env, entity, process_3_res, process_4_q):
    print(f' {env.now} customer {entity.id} in process 3')
    with process_3_res.request() as res_req:
        yield res_req
        yield env.timeout(np.random.exponential(mu[2]))
        yield process_4_q.put(entity)

def process4_broker(env, process_4_q, process_4_res):
    while True:
        res_req = process_4_res.request()
        yield res_req
        entity = yield process_3_q.get()
        entity.res_req = res_req
        env.process(process4(env,entity,process_4_res))

def process4(env, entity, process_4_res, process_4_q):
    print(f' {env.now} customer {entity.id} in process 4')
    with process_4_res.request() as res_req:
        yield res_req
        yield env.timeout(np.random.exponential(mu[3]))
        yield process_4_res.release(entity.res_req)
        print(f' {env.now} customer {entity.id} leaves system')
        
def gen_entities(env, process_0_res, process_1_q):
    next_id = 1
    while True:
        yield env.timeout(np.random.exponential(labda))
        entity = Entity()
        entity.id = next_id
        next_id += 1
        env.process(process0(env, entity, process_0_res, process_1_q))

env = simpy.Environment()
process_0_res = simpy.Resource(env, capacity = 1)
process_1_res = simpy.Resource(env, capacity = 1)
process_2_res = simpy.Resource(env, capacity = 1)
process_3_res = simpy.Resource(env, capacity = 1)
process_4_res = simpy.Resource(env, capacity = 1)

process_1_q = simpy.Store(env, capacity = 5)
process_2_q = simpy.Store(env, capacity = 4)
process_3_q = simpy.Store(env, capacity = 3)
process_4_q = simpy.Store(env, capacity = 2)

env.process(gen_entities(env, process_0_res, process_1_q))

env.process(process1_broker(env, process_1_q, process_1_res))
env.process(process2_broker(env, process_2_q, process_2_res))
env.process(process3_broker(env, process_3_q, process_3_res))
env.process(process4_broker(env, process_4_q, process_4_res)) 

env.run(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a store with a capacity to act as a blocking queue

Process 1 will not release its process 1 resource until the entity can be put into the store.  If the store is at capacity, it will block the put until process 2 pulls a entity from the store.

To manage the store, I have a broker process that matches entities in the store with process 2 resources.  When a match is made process 2 starts.

```
"""
Demostrates one way to do a blocking queue
where a queue has a size limit and will
'block' arrivals whe the queue is at that limit

sim two processes were the first process has a unlimited queue
and second process with a limited blocking queue.

A entity will not releases its resource from the first process
until it can advance to the second process's queue

Uses a simpy store to queue entities for process 2
and a broker process to match entities from the store
with process 2 resources then starts process 2 when match is made

Programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random

class Entity(object):
    """
    Quick class to track entities
    dynamicly will add id, and resouce request
    """
    pass

def process1(env, entity, process_1_res, process_2_q):
    """
    First process with a unlimited queue
    """
    print(f'{env.now} entity {entity.id} has arrived in process 1')

    with process_1_res.request() as res_req:
        print(f'{env.now} process 1 queue size {len(process_1_res.queue)}')
        
        yield res_req
        print(f'{env.now} entity {entity.id} has seized a process 1 resource')

        yield env.timeout(random.uniform(1,5))
        print(f'{env.now} entity {entity.id} has finished process 1')

        # this put will block if the store is at compacity
        yield process_2_q.put(entity)
        print(f'{env.now} entity {entity.id} has advance to process 2 queue')
    
    print(f'{env.now} process 1 queue size {len(process_1_res.queue)}')

def process2_broker(env, process_2_q, process_2_res):
    """
    When a resouce for process 2 is available, will pull
    and entity from the store beign uses at the process 2's
    blocking queue
    """

    while True:
        print(f'{env.now} process 2 queue size {len(process_2_q.items)}')

        # wait for a resouce to become avaliable
        res_req = process_2_res.request()
        yield res_req

        # wait for a entity to be avaliable
        entity = yield process_2_q.get() 

        # save the resouce request so we can release it later
        entity.res_req = res_req  

        # start process 2, no yield here, start the next match imediatly
        env.process(process2(env, entity, process_2_res))

def process2(env, entity, process_2_res):
    """
    Process 2 where a entiy has already been matched with
    a resouce in the broker
    """

    print(f'{env.now} entity {entity.id} has started process 2')

    yield env.timeout(random.uniform(1,10))

    print(f'{env.now} entity {entity.id} has finished process 2')

    # the resouce request was saved in the broker so it could be released now
    process_2_res.release(entity.res_req)

def gen_entities(env, process_1_res, process_2_q):
    """
    Generates a stream of entities to be processed
    starting with process 1
    """

    next_id = 1

    while True:
        yield env.timeout(random.uniform(1,3))

        entity = Entity()
        entity.id = next_id
        next_id += 1

        env.process(process1(env, entity, process_1_res, process_2_q))

# boot up
env = env = simpy.Environment()

# resouces for processes
process_1_res = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=3)
process_2_res = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=2)

# used as blocking queue for process 2
process_2_q = simpy.Store(env,capacity=5)

env.process(gen_entities(env, process_1_res, process_2_q))
env.process(process2_broker(env, process_2_q, process_2_res))

env.run(100)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and might come back with additional questions.